# How did be- beget new meanings, when prefixed to "soigner" and "soin"?

Tags: préfixes

I have been learning French many years. I knew that [*soin*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/soin) means "care", but I never affiliated it with *besoin*! I never knew that [*besoin*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/besoin) = [***be-*** + *soin*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besoin#Etymology), which means "need"!
How did the prefix ***be-*** turn "care" into "need"?!?!?

[*besogne* means work or job](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/besogne), [*besogneux* "hard-working"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/besogneux), and [*besogner* travailler péniblement](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/besogner). Same question...how did the prefix ***be-*** transmogrify "care" into "work or job" and hard work?!?!?

What exactly does ***be-*** mean when prefixing *soin*?  How did ***be-*** synergize all these separate self-determining meanings emergentistically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix ***be-*** predates French and didn't turn one meaning to the other. *Soin*, *besoin* and *besogne* all come from the single (reconstructed) proto-germanic word ****sunnju*** / ****sunni*** / ****sunnija*** that already had multiple meanings, including "care" and "need".

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/sunnju) ***Sunnju***:

> 1. responsibility
> 2. **care**; concern
> 3. worry; anxiety
> 4. **need**

The prefix *be-* comes from the Frankish *bi-* ("Near": German *bei*, English "by").

[image]

Comment: I like your colorful flow chart! Did you create it yourself? Your answer raises a new question...why does _*sunnju_ mean both **care** and **need**?

Comment: @Guest Thanks! I was inspired by [etymologeek.com](https://etymologeek.com/). I wanted to merge [*soin*](https://etymologeek.com/fra/soin) and [*besoin*](https://etymologeek.com/fra/besoin) but didn't find a way with the site so did the graph myself. About the **sunnju* meanings, The source might be the [*Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch*](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/lire/170/272)

Comment: In Italian *avere bisogno di* is used in the same sense as *avoir besoin de* in French, which probably underscores that *be-* predates French.

Comment: What software did you use to create this chart? Can you elaborate why _*sunnju_ mean both **care** and **need**?

Comment: @Guest 1. I used [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) 2. That's stated in the Wiktionary along with this disclaimer:  *This Proto-West Germanic entry contains reconstructed terms and roots. As such, the term(s) in this entry are not directly attested, but are hypothesized to have existed based on comparative evidence.*

Answer (score 0):

[Besoin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/besoin) is a word by itself, there is no prefix. It is not the concatenation of “be” and “soin”.

You can see [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/besoin) the etymology.

Same remarks for [besogne](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/besogne)